# DevExpress: How to use ObjectFormatter.Format for collections

Tags: c#, collections, format, devexpress, xaf

I have dynamically created collection elements. 
I try to do something like this

```
String format = "{0:Document.Contragent.BDContragentInfo[Field.Caption == 'Email'].Single(Value)}";
String generatedNumber = ObjectFormatter.Format(format, formatObjectHelper);
```

There's an error, that there's no such field like 'Document.Contragent.BDContragentInfo[Field.Caption == 'Email'].Single(Value) '

But it works for CriteriaOperator. Is there a way to solve this problem?

**UPD:**
As a temporary solution used ObjectSpace.GetEvaluator(...).Evaluate() method to evaluate object by criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from DE. The answer is I can't do this. So if you have such problem, use either my solution in UPD section or use the DE answer solution
https://www.devexpress.com/support/center/Question/Details/T346980